# Django. How i can run my function every 5 second and update the page

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, delay

I have a Django app. I want that every 5 seconds, the script will update DB dates and reload my page.
I tried with a simple: `while()`, but this stopped all code. I tried with async function, but nothing is working

```
My code: `from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import models
from main.models import Prices
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
# Create your views here.

timeout = 5

def parseSite():
        Prices.objects.all().delete()
        URL = "https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin"
        page =  requests.get(URL)
        soup =  BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        cont =  soup.find(class_="coin-info").find_all(class_="coin-info-block")
        final_price =  cont[0].find(class_="price-large").text
        bitoc =  Prices(curency_type = "bitcoin", curency_price = final_price)
        bitoc.save()

parseSite()


def dates():
   bitoc2 = Prices.objects.get(curency_type= "bitcoin")
   return bitoc2



def index(request):
    data = dates()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'data': data})
`
```

Comment: use threading.Timer to run a function at continous intervals. Use meta tag to refresh webpage every 5 seconds

Comment: Web socket + Django channels is the solution to update the page content real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really need to refresh the page, so usin html Meta tag could be a solution. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` and `5` is in seconds. but if you need realtime changes in a part of a page, as [Erfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10529723/erfan) mentioned use `websocket & djnago-channels,...`